# how to add buttons that appear dynamically in a dialog using android studio

Tags: android, dialog

I have a dialog that shows an error message,
i know i can take that error message and just make it invisible, and visible in the code, 
but then the Dialog would still save room in it and it will just show as a white space.

I want the error message to be added dynamical so if no error message will be shown the dialog will be sized accordingly.

how do i do that ?

here is my Dialog >

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="14">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/barcode_activity_input_editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Serial Number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="14" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/barcode_activity_button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/barcode_activity_manual_input_check_box"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/barcode_activity_button_ok"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/barcode_activity_manual_input_check_box"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/barcode_activity_button_cancel"
        android:text="Ok" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/barcode_activity_text_view_warning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textContainer"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/barcode_activity_image_view_warning"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Serial doesn't match Workorder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#f00000"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/barcode_activity_image_view_warning"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textContainer"
        android:background="@drawable/warning" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/barcode_activity_manual_input_check_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/barcode_activity_image_view_warning"
        android:text="Allow Serial In Workorder"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my main file >

```
 inputFieldDialog = new Dialog(this); // CASTING
        //inputFieldDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        inputFieldDialog.setContentView(R.layout.aligment_manager_manual_input_layout); // INFLATING VIEW

        Button cancelInputButton, confirmInputButton; //declaring BOXES
        final EditText inputField;
        TextView warningTextView;
        ImageView warningImageView;
        CheckBox warningCheckBox;

        cancelInputButton = (Button) inputFieldDialog.findViewById(R.id.barcode_activity_button_cancel); //casting
        confirmInputButton = (Button) inputFieldDialog.findViewById(R.id.barcode_activity_button_ok); //casting
        inputField = (EditText) inputFieldDialog.findViewById(R.id.barcode_activity_input_editText); //casting

        warningTextView = (TextView) inputFieldDialog.findViewById(R.id.barcode_activity_text_view_warning); //casting
        warningImageView = (ImageView) inputFieldDialog.findViewById(R.id.barcode_activity_image_view_warning); //casting
        warningCheckBox = (CheckBox) inputFieldDialog.findViewById(R.id.barcode_activity_manual_input_check_box); //casting

        warningTextView.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE); //sets warnings invisible
        warningImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE); //sets warnings invisible
        warningCheckBox.setVisibility(CheckBox.INVISIBLE); //sets warnings invisible



        cancelInputButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //listeners for the buttons
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                inputFieldDialog.hide();
            }
        });

        confirmInputButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //listeners for the buttons
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                scanResults = String.valueOf(inputField.getText());

                scanBarcodeText.setText(inputField.getText());

                editor.putString("boxID", String.valueOf(inputField.getText())); //saves the data as antenaNamein shared prefrences
                editor.commit();

                if (checkIfIdMatched(String.valueOf(inputField.getText())) == true) { //checkks if id is maching the one in the workorder

                    aligmentManagerClass.scanFromBarcodeApproved(); //ID MACHED

                    if (mainDialog != null) {
                        mainDialog.show();
                    }

                    loaderScreenMainText.setText("initlizing WiFi");//shows the user on screen message

                    wifiWrapper myWifiWrapper = new wifiWrapper(); //- INIZILIZING WIFI
                    myWifiWrapper.checkWifiState(getApplication(), callbackFunctionForisWifiOn);

                } else {

                    loaderScreenMainText.setText("Scan Doesn't Match Data In Workoder"); // notify onScreen User

                    if (mainDialog != null) { // hides the loading dialog
                        mainDialog.hide();
                    }

                    AlertDialog wrongNumberDialog = getAlertDialogForWrongId(); //shows to user alert dialog for Wrong Number

                    wrongNumberDialog.show(); // show it


                }


            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remove white space...
Use "View.GONE" property of setVisibility() method rather than "TextView.INVISIBLE".

Set below code for hide views

```
warningTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
warningImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
warningCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And for visible view just user

```
warningTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
warningImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
warningCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: WOW genius !! thnx !

Comment: Most Welcome...(Thanks @user2560571)

Comment: BTW @Jaldeep Asodariya why do i get - points for this question ?

Comment: I have vote up your comment "WOW genius !! thnx !", because it's really useful for me to help you and it's encourage to me for more sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can add buttons dynamically by creating buttons in Java file

Add this XML to dialog like dialog.addView(...)

Then Create Dynamically Buttons by according to values like

for(){

Create Buttons and add to above layout

layout.addView(button);

}

Hope it will help.